# VBA calling DLL issue encountered Error 453

Tags: c#, excel, vba, dll

I am a beginner and have encountered some difficulties in my recent learning. I want to call a DLL in VBA. Below are my C# code and VBA code respectively.

C#(ClassLibrary):

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace helloworld
    {
        public class Class1
        {
            [ComVisible(true)]
            public string GetMessage()
            {
                return "Hello, World!";
            }
        }
    }
```

VBA:

```vb
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetMessage Lib ""C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\helloworld\helloworld\bin\x64\Debug\helloworld.dll"" () As String
    
    Sub CallDLL()
        Dim message As String
        message = GetMessage()
        MsgBox message
    End Sub
```

I have searched a lot of information but still haven't found a solution. My Excel is 64-bit, and I have also changed the DLL to x64. My Visual Studio version is 2015 and target framework is .NET framwork 4.5.

Comment: Is the path correct? `C:\Users\Documents` looks suspicious, usually it should be something like `C:\Users\EXCUSEME\Documents`

Comment: Yes, the path is correct, some redaction was done because it includes my name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying what you're doing is wrong, but it's not how I would do this. As far as I know "Declare" in VBA/6 is to access functions in native dlls - C-type dlls.

It looks like you are trying to expose your C# code as a COM visible class.
In that case, COM interface doesn't work the same as C-style interface.

You can add a COM dll to your VBA project from the Tools->References menu.
Browse & select your dll from that dialog.
When you do that VBA will usually automatically call DllRegisterServer for you.
If you go into the VBA Object Browser after adding the reference you should see the new classes are available.

COM does not usually find assemblies by file path - the DllRegisterServer method usually creates a link between the CLSID & physical file in the Windows registry.
Keep that in mind for deployment.
There's also the option of using a manifest for registration-free COM.
That might not work here because you probably can't manifest the VBA host.